# How do you write this regex in VBA word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a regex in VBA word where two spaces followed by a number is replaced with one space followed by a number.  This is what I've come up with but it doesn't work:

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Text = "(\s\s\d)"
    .Replacement.Text = "(\s\d)"
    .Forward = True
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .MatchWildcards = True

End With
ActiveDocument.Content.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

I do not get any error message, rather no effects occur in my doc.

The official documentation is located here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

#

UPDATE

I tried using the advanced find and replace and I checked the `use wild cards` and I put in

```
Find:  [0-9]
Replace: [0-9]
```

That's 2 spaces between Find: and [ and one space between Replace: and [ but it replaced the string: 'hey  8' with 'hey [0-9]'.

Comment: Note: The documentation you linked to is .Net documentation, which is nothing to do with VBA.

Comment: The documentation you linked has absolutely nothing to do with VBA. VBA is not VB.Net or VB or VBScript. Just because they all start with VB does not mean they're the same, any more than a **cat** and a **car** and a **carrot** are all the same because they start with **ca**. See http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wildcards` to Find and replace:

Find: `SpaceSpace([0-9])` (Two spaces in front of `([0-9])`)

Replace: `Space\1` (Single space and `\1`)

Similar to `Regex`, `()` is used for grouping in `wildcards`. `\1` represents the first group in your text that is found, which is a number in this case.

If you are uncertain about the number of spaces that can come before your text, you could use `Space{1,}` which tells word to find any number of `Spaces`.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that.